# How to create a 2 dimensional array from an associative array in php

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

i need to convert a associative array to a 2 dimensional array in php, the origin array is as followed

```
    array:7 [▼
  "data" => "data"
  "id_1553539135251" => "<p>nsmn</p>"
  "about" => "about"
  "id_1553539141598" => "<p>uiu</p>"
```

my code

```
        $data = $request->all();
        $json = array();
        foreach($data as $key => $value){

            if(strpos($key, 'id') !== false){
                $json[$key]['content'] = $value;
            }
        }
```

i need the output of the following for each to be

```
array:3 [▼
  "id_1553539135251" => array:1 [▼
    "content" => "<p>nsmn</p>"
    "data" => "data"
]
  "id_1553539141598" => array:1 [▼
    "content" => "<p>uiu</p>"
    "about" => "about"
  ]
]
```

but my code outputs

```
array:3 [▼
  "id_1553539135251" => array:1 [▼
    "content" => "<p>nsmn</p>"
  ]
  "id_1553539138029" => array:1 [▼
    "content" => "<p>jjkjk</p>"
  ]
  "id_1553539141598" => array:1 [▼
    "content" => "<p>uiu</p>"
  ]
]
```

guidance on how to achieve the desired output is appreciated.

Comment: With the code you posted the problem isn't really clear. From the last 2 blocks the only difference seems to be that you don't have the header in there. Is that all you're missing?

Comment: you have no `"header"` neither in your initial data nor in your transformation loop. So why do you expect to get it in your result array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<?php
$test=array(
  array(

   "data" => "data",
    "id_1553539135251" => "<p>nsmn</p>",
    "about" => "about",
    "id_1553539141598" => "<p>uiu</p>"
  ),
);
$output=array();
foreach($test as $item){
 $i=0;
 $tt='';
 foreach($item as $k=>$v){
  
  if(strpos($k, 'id') !== false){
   $output[$k]=array(
     'content'=>$item[$k],
     'header'=>$tt,
  );
  }else{
   $tt=$v; 
  }
 }
}
print_r($output);
```